# Is there a way to add a constant number to a group of cells?

Tags: excel, vba

This should be super simple. Just want to take a column of cells with numerical values and add a value (say 650) to every one of those cells. It's thousands of cells, so I was thinking it would be pretty inefficient to do a for loop that stores a value, adds 650, then replaces the cell with the new value. That might be what's necessary, but was hoping there was a simpler solution.

Comment: Put 650 in a new cell, copy, then select the cells > Paste Special > Add?

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, can't believe I didn't know that existed. Thank you!

Comment: @BigBen That should be added as an answer. I would say that is not general knowledge for most users...

Comment: @Tragamor - I've voted to close this question as it's not related to programming per se... perhaps better suited for Super User.